# Output of array not correct extra letters being added

Tags: javascript

So I have an issue with showing my search results in the correct format. I’m using ajax to get my data from the server side. I have a function that shows the results of a search and outputs it in a particular way and my issue is that it isn’t outputting some of the values correct so I have a location tag which in the search bar should come up as:

```
L1 Disneyland 
L2,L3 Six flags 
L2 Thorpe Park
```

However at the moment it doesn’t show in my search bar in the correct format when I have two locations attached to a place:

```
L1 Disneyland 
L2, L, L, L3 Six flags 
L2 Thorpe Park
```

I have an multidimensional array called results:

```
results = array(
    array(
        'id' => '10045',
        'name' => 'Disneyland',
        'location' => '1’
    ),
    array(
        'id' => '5465',
        'name' => 'six flags',
        'location' => '2,3'
    )
);
```

The contents of searchResults[‘results’] when console logged shows:

```
{id: “10045”, name: “Disneyland”, location: “1”}

{id: “5465”, name: “Six flags”, location: “2, 3”}
```

This is the part of my code where I know there is an issue but I’m not sure what it is:

```
for(searchResult in searchResults[‘results’]){

var resultLocationLabel = “”;

for( var i=0; i < searchResults[‘results’][searchResult][‘location’].length; i++) {
    resultLocationLabel = “L”+searchResults[‘results’][searchResults][‘location’][i] + “ “;
}
```

Comment: please add `searchResults` array data.

Comment: @RahulKumar the array data is in the second to last box this is what comes up when I console log

Comment: You have white space in `location: “2, 3”`, So the length is 4 (including comma), So please try `searchResults[‘results’][searchResult][‘location’].split(",").length` and try to trim white space when append data

Comment: @RinshanKolayil it’s gotten rid of the extra Ls however it now doesn’t recognise that I have an extra location e.g. for six flags it’s only showing “L2 L,” instead of “L2,L3”

Comment: You can even try `var resultLocationLabel = "L" + searchResults[‘results’][searchResult][‘location’].replaceAll(", ",",L");`  if structure of `location` is same, but following answer is suggested one because you have white space in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Array.split(",")` and then trim `whitespaces`

```
for (searchResult in searchResults[‘results’]) {
  var resultLocationLabel = “”;
  const locations = searchResults[‘results’][searchResult][‘location’].split(",");
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    resultLocationLabel += “L”+locations[i].trim() + “ “;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked once I added the += to resultLocationLabel

Comment: yes correct, we need to `concatenate` the resultLocationLabel.